# CRMSDK QueryExpression didn't return all the related attributes

Tags: azure-functions, crm, dynamics-crm-sdk

I have one Azure Function, it is built with crmsdk and framework 4.6.2.
The QueryExpression query returns two fields but misses the other three attributes, two fields contain correct information.
I converted QueryExpression to FetchXML and use that in XrmTool box, it retrieves all data and field name are all correct.
I tried different CRM environment and QueryExpression gets all attributes, it seems like environment related.
I then checked the data and all the five attributes have value.
Has anyone seen such strange issue?
Thanks.

I expected queryexpression returns all attributes.

```
public IEnumerable<ReadyDocketLineDto> GetDocketLinesToBeProcessed()
    {
        var qryDocketLine = new QueryExpression(company_cpseventdocketline.EntityLogicalName);

        #region get docket line
        qryDocketLine.ColumnSet.AddColumns(
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.Id,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_docketlinetypecode,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_paymentclassificationid,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_name,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_amountincludingGST,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_amountexcludingGST,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_cpseventdocketid,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.CreatedBy,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_recharge_nonbillable,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.CreatedOn,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_classificationreason
            );

        qryDocketLine.Criteria.AddCondition(company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.StatusCode, ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)company_cpseventdocketline_StatusCode.Ready);
        qryDocketLine.Criteria.AddCondition(company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_cpseventdocketid, ConditionOperator.NotNull);
        qryDocketLine.Criteria.AddCondition(company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_name, ConditionOperator.Equal, "DLN-0003995255");
        #endregion

        #region link to docket
        var lnkDocketLineToDocket = qryDocketLine.AddLink(
            company_cpseventdocket.EntityLogicalName,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_cpseventdocketid,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.Id,
            JoinOperator.LeftOuter
            );

        lnkDocketLineToDocket.EntityAlias = "docket";

        lnkDocketLineToDocket.Columns.AddColumns(
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_OutFreeDistance,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_OutExcessDistance,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_TowFreeDistance,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_TowExcessDistance,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_calculatedattendancedistance,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_calculatedtowingdistance,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_docketnumber,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_eventdispositioncodes,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_customerid,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_accountid,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_suburb,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.CreatedBy,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_cpsmemberclubid,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_cpsprogramid,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_cpsproductid,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_vehicleregistration,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_eventoccurredon,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_CPSeventid
        );

        #endregion

        #region link to agreement
        var lnkDocketLineToAgreement = qryDocketLine.AddLink(
           company_vendoragreement.EntityLogicalName,
           company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_agreementid,
           company_vendoragreement.Fields.Id,
           JoinOperator.LeftOuter);

        lnkDocketLineToAgreement.EntityAlias = "agreement";

        lnkDocketLineToAgreement.Columns.AddColumns(
            company_vendoragreement.PrimaryNameAttribute,
            company_vendoragreement.Fields.company_DAXVendorID,
            company_vendoragreement.Fields.StateCode,
            company_vendoragreement.Fields.StatusCode,
            company_vendoragreement.Fields.company_teamsupplier);
        #endregion

        #region link to vendor
        var lnkDocketLineToAgreementToVendor = lnkDocketLineToAgreement.AddLink(
            company_vendor.EntityLogicalName,
            company_vendoragreement.Fields.company_vendorid,
            company_vendor.Fields.Id,
            JoinOperator.LeftOuter);

        lnkDocketLineToAgreementToVendor.EntityAlias = "vendor";

        lnkDocketLineToAgreementToVendor.Columns.AddColumns(company_vendor.Fields.company_gstapplicable);

        #endregion

        #region link to payment classification
        var lnkDocketLineToPaymentClassification = qryDocketLine.AddLink(
            company_paymentclassification.EntityLogicalName,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.company_paymentclassificationid,
            company_paymentclassification.Fields.company_paymentclassificationId,
            JoinOperator.LeftOuter);

        lnkDocketLineToPaymentClassification.EntityAlias = "classificationcode";

        lnkDocketLineToPaymentClassification.Columns.AddColumns(
            company_paymentclassification.Fields.company_name,
            company_paymentclassification.Fields.company_paymentclassificationId,
            company_paymentclassification.Fields.company_glaccount,
            company_paymentclassification.Fields.company_classificationcode,
            company_paymentclassification.Fields.company_nonbillableglaccount
        );
        #endregion

        #region  link to system user who created the docketline
        var linkDocketLineToSystemUser = qryDocketLine.AddLink(
            SystemUser.EntityLogicalName,
            company_cpseventdocketline.Fields.CreatedBy,
            SystemUser.PrimaryIdAttribute,
            JoinOperator.LeftOuter
            );
        linkDocketLineToSystemUser.EntityAlias = "systemuser";
        linkDocketLineToSystemUser.Columns.AddColumns(SystemUser.Fields.DomainName);

        #endregion

        #region get the DAX transaction mappings
        List<company_cpsdaxtransactionmapping> daxTxnMappings = new List<company_cpsdaxtransactionmapping>();

        var qryDaxTxnMappings = new QueryExpression(company_cpsdaxtransactionmapping.EntityLogicalName);
        qryDaxTxnMappings.Criteria.AddCondition(company_cpsdaxtransactionmapping.Fields.StateCode, ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)company_cpsdaxtransactionmappingState.Active);
        qryDaxTxnMappings.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

        var results = organisationService.RetrieveMultiple(qryDaxTxnMappings);
        daxTxnMappings = results.Entities.Cast<company_cpsdaxtransactionmapping>().ToList();
        #endregion

        #region link to the extgernal system reference to get the dax customer id
        var lnkDocketToExternalSystemReference = lnkDocketLineToDocket.AddLink(
            company_externalsystemreference.EntityLogicalName,
            company_cpseventdocket.Fields.company_accountid,
            company_externalsystemreference.Fields.company_Customer,
            JoinOperator.LeftOuter
            );
        lnkDocketToExternalSystemReference.EntityAlias = "externalsystemreference";
        lnkDocketToExternalSystemReference.Columns.AddColumns(company_externalsystemreference.Fields.company_SystemIdentifier);
        lnkDocketToExternalSystemReference.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(company_externalsystemreference.Fields.company_externalsystemid, ConditionOperator.Equal, company_externalsystem.RecordIds.DAXCustomer));

        #endregion

        var docketLines = bulkRequestHelper.RetrieveMultiple(qryDocketLine);

        foreach (var dl in docketLines)
        {
            yield return ConvertEntityToDocketLineDto(dl, daxTxnMappings);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code?

Comment: Also I checked request and response with fiddler, the sender request contains 5 attributes, but response only have 2, then I checked the column security, they are all ok